COPY command activity not picking up the file for specified PATTERN
I've specified PATTERN = 'DS_STORAGE_2024.csv' its not picking up the file however if i use PATTERN = '.*DS_STORAGE_.*' its working however I do not want this pattern as it will pick file having text or characters before or after DS_STORAGE_
Below is the query I've used
COPY INTO DATABASE.SCHEMA.LOAD_TABLE (ID, NAME)
FROM 
(
SELECT SRC.$1,
SRC.$2
FROM @EXTERNAL_STAGE/LANDING AS SRC
)
FILE_FORMAT = 'CSV'
PATTERN = 'DS_STORAGE_2024.csv'

Below are the other patterns i've tried but still not working
DS_STORAGE_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.csv
DS_STORAGE_2024\.csv
Please help if there is any workaround ?

Hi - please update your question with the full COPY command that you are using

@NickW I've added the full Copy command

Try this: PATTERN = '.*DS_STORAGE_2024.csv'

Thanks @NickW I've found the resolution in the snowflake documentation.
I need to use path like this: PATTERN = 'SOURCEFOLDER/DS_STORAGE_2024.csv'
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table#optional-parameters

This is resolved now  as per snowflake documentation need to use this pattern
PATTERN = 'SOURCE_FOLDER/DS_STORAGE_2024/.csv'
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table#optional-parameters
